# Get values from mongoDB column into HTML table using Django

Tags: python, html, django, mongodb, pymongo

I want to get the values from a mongoDB column inside a HTML Table.

This is in views.py

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pymongo.read_preferences import ReadPreference


myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://00.00.00.0:27017")
mydb = myclient["dbName"]
mycol = mydb["thePages"]

def pages(request):
  for x in mycol.find({},{ "_id": 0, "url": 1 }):
    return HttpResponse("<table border=1><tr><td> " + str(x) + "</td></tr></table>")
```

urls.py:

```
 path('page/thePages', views.thePages, name = 'thePages'),
```

Result:

```
{'pageName': 'Google'}
```

Expected Result:

```
Google
Bing
Facebook
StackOverflow
```

I am new to Django. Please help. I know I need a loop to get all the values in the column and in the format shown above. I need a way to go about it. Any help would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def pages(request):
    table_start = "<table border=1><tr>"
    table_end = "</tr></table>"
    table_data = []
    for x in mycol.find({}, {"_id": 0, "url": 1}):
        if 'pageName' in x:
            table_data.append("<td> " + x['pageName'] + "</td>")
    return HttpResponse(table_start + ' '.join(table_data) + table_end)
```

Hope this helps! You to save all results before returning an HTML response.

Comment: I am also adding an array with code `for x in mycol.aggregate([{"$unwind":"$tags"},{'$match': {'tags.tag.name':'A A',}},{'$project': {'url': 1,  'tags.tag.name': 1, '_id': 0}},]):`  but when I do `table_data.append("<tr><td>" + x['url'] + "</td><td>" + json.dumps(tags.tag.name) +  "</td></tr>")` I am getting a `NameError name 'tags' is not defined` error

Comment: `json.dumps('tags.tag.name')` I guess this is the reason. Give key name in a single quote.

Comment: But that returns the string `tags.tag.name`

Comment: Could you please share the `x` variable output?

Comment: `x = {'tags': {'tag': {'name': 'A A'}},
 'url': 'https://www.google.com'}`

Comment: `json.dumps(x['tags']['tag']['name'])` try this

Comment: Can you please help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52397507/template-render-is-not-passing-pymongo-aggregate-variable-to-template?